# PHP: Removing object by reference from associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a recursive function searching an object by index in a multidimensional, associative array.

```
$settings = array(
'title' => new XCPreferenceShortText('title'),
'html' => new XCPreferenceLongText('html'),
'_blog' => array(
    '_blog' => new XCPreferenceHeading('blog'),
    'acceptcomments' => new XCPreferenceBoolean('acceptcomments'),
    'per_page' => new XCPreferenceNumberSet('per_page')
),
'_publishing' => array(
    '_publishing' => new XCPreferenceHeading('publishing'),
    'published' => new XCPreferenceBoolean('published'),
    'publishon' => new XCPreferenceDate('publishon'),
)
);
```

The code traverses the array and whenever `is_array($value)` returns true, it recurses the whole thing.

```
function &find($idx, $pref_array = false) {

    if ($pref_array === false)
        $pref_array = &$this->preferences;

    foreach ($pref_array as $key => $data) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $res = $this->find($idx, $data);
            if ($res !== false)
                return $res;
        }
        else if ($key == $idx)
            return $pref_array[$idx];
    }

    return false;
}
```

This function finds (and returns a reference to the result) an object associated to a given key – but when I store the return value / reference in a variable and set that var to null, this has no effect on the actual element in the "original" array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improved the function call as Artefacto suggested – but the function still didn't return a reference for elements retrieved by recursion only.

The mistake was, in this case, the recursion call itself. Below you will find an adjusted version which works for me:

```
foreach ($pref_array as $key => $data) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $res = &$this->find($idx, &$pref_array[$key]);
            if ($res !== false)
                return $res;
        }
        else if ($key == $idx) {
            return $pref_array[$idx];
        }
    }
```

Calling `&$this->find($idx, $data);` before was wrong as `$data` actually was no reference. In order to get a reference to the array I just had to fetch the array from the *referenced* variable (`$pref_array`).

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function like this:

```
$value = &find($idx);
$value = null;
//just to be safe, in case you re-use $value later on
unset($value);
```

Saying the function returns by reference is insufficient to create a store a reference on calling.

By the way, you should be aware an iterator called [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://www.php.net/RecursiveArrayIterator) exists.

Comment: (Sorry to annoy you again) I don't think so... this doesn't clear the array's reference to the object found, only a new reference created when `find` returns. Or does it?

Comment: @Mvan Well, you can test it: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ISR2lq In place of the object is now a NULL.

Comment: @ban Read the question. All the OP wants to do is to replace the value in the array with `NULL`. He doesn't want to unset the array element. There is actually a caveat to my answer: `$value = null;` might actually not replace the object with NULL in one very particular situation -- when `$value` is a proxy object. I don't think that's a very relevant objection in this case, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll need to look into PHP references. And thank you even more for the online PHP interpreter that I couldn't find when I needed it.